# Publish in Tridion 2011 SP1 using CoreService 2010 don't return any publishing transactions

Tags: soap, tridion, tridion-2011

I am trying to publish a single Component in Tridion using the CoreService 2010 Basic HTTP interface.

Using Soap UI, I am sending

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body>
    <ns4:Publish xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/R6" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:ns3="http://www.sdltridion.com/Security" xmlns:ns4="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2010" xmlns:ns5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
      <ns4:ids>
        <ns2:string>tcm:292-39250</ns2:string>
      </ns4:ids>
      <ns4:publishInstruction>
        <ResolveInstruction>
          <IncludeChildPublications>true</IncludeChildPublications>
          <IncludeComponentLinks>false</IncludeComponentLinks>
          <IncludeWorkflow>false</IncludeWorkflow>
        </ResolveInstruction>
        <RenderInstruction/>
      </ns4:publishInstruction>
      <ns4:targets>
        <ns2:string>tcm:0-5-65537</ns2:string>
      </ns4:targets>
      <ns4:priority>Normal</ns4:priority>
      <ns4:readOptions>
        <ns4:LoadFlags>None</ns4:LoadFlags>
      </ns4:readOptions>
    </ns4:Publish>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

And then receiving:

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Header>
      <ActivityId CorrelationId="7bfbbb48-8111-40ba-9e6e-8a7073a21a09" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ActivityId>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <PublishResponse xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2010">
         <PublishResult xmlns:a="http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/R6" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
      </PublishResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I am expecting to see a PublicationTransaction here, what am I doing wrong?

I am based my request on this url http://blog.building-blocks.com/publishing-components-using-the-core-service-in-sdl-tridion-2011, it doesn't appear I need much more, but perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: Is your item entering the publishing queue?

Comment: I haven't yet gotten SoapUI to work, but I suspect your `<ns4:LoadFlags>None</ns4:LoadFlags>` may have something to do with not getting anything more useful. Does the item enter into the Publish Queue, as Chris asked?

Comment: @Tommy: did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Sorry, I was unable to get online most of today. But no, the item does not go into the publishing queue (and never change status to publish). I tried commenting out the readOptions in the request, but getting same result. For SoapUI I use version 4.5.0, there is a documented bug in 4.5.1 so it doesn't work with Tridion (and services accessed in the same way)

Comment: OK, now I am getting a Publishing Transaction, I tried publishing in the Web UI and trace it with Fiddler and I noticed it was sending tcm:0-5-66538 in the json request. So I tried using that instead of "tcm:0-5-66537". But that puzzles me a bit as I thought "65538" was a "target type", not a "publication target" (65537). It seems it may just my be understanding of the difference between the two that is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Publishing is an action which is done against a (Publication) Target Type, but you are mentioning a Publication Target (tcm:0-5-65537) in your request.

A (Publication) Target Type is the "logical" item which is known to SDL Tridion Users (i.e. Authors and Editors). It is the item where security is also set on and it is the item which is selected in the UI when a user wants to publish something. Typical names are "staging" and "live". The official documentation words it as follows: A Target Type specifies a user-friendly name for one or more Publication Targets and specifies permission settings for the target(s).

The Publication Target is more or less the "technical" item, it contains the different destinations and the configuration for which Publication this target is enabled. This is linked to the Target Type in its properties. Unfortunately typical names for Publication targets are also "staging" and "live", which is where the initial confusion comes from. The official documentation words it as: A Publication Target defines the information required to publish content using different protocols.

The item types in the URI can show you the difference:

```
65537 = Publication Target
65538 = Target Type
```

Comment: Thank you for that detailed feedback, I had reached somewhat of a similar understanding on my own, but you cleared it up a bit more for me.